# Tomcat configure external properties and log files

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j

I have a webapp deployed in a Tomcat7 in *webapps/webapp*. Inside this webapp there a *logback.xml* and *persistence.property* files.

When I start the server this files are taken into consideration. I'd like tomcat to load this files from an external directory. e.g. */home/tomcat/conf*

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [VirtualWebappLoader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html#VirtualWebappLoader_Implementation) to load logback.xml and persistence.property from an external directory.

The configuration looks like this:

```
<Context ...>
  <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/home/tomcat/conf" />
</Context>
```

Hope this helps.